# Selecting a string with funny character from mysqli using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, special-characters

So I'm trying to find "Wrocław" in my Mysql table with collation utf8_general_ci.

In PHP, I'm using this code

```
$query = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * 
  FROM locations
 WHERE location 
  LIKE 'Wrocław'
") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { echo'found it'; exit; }
```

However, I'm not getting any results. I *will* get a result when searching for "Barcelona". So I'm guessing that the problem is due to the funny character "ł".

When entering the above Query in PhpMyAdmin, I am in fact finding the row containing "Wrocław" which is the expect result.

Any idea why it's not working on the PHP side? I've also tried to previously use mysqli_real_escape_string on Wrocław

Thanks!

Comment: What is the encoding of your php source file?

Comment: When using PHPMyAdmin, and when querying directly, are you using the same version of MySQL?

Comment: @Lars UTF-8 is the encoding

Comment: @Strawberry yes

Comment: @EliâMelfior thank you for your comment, "SELECT *" is used here for illustrations purposes only

Comment: Try this:
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4"),
(it's just a guess)

Somehow you have to escape the character
More information here:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Try this: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` or, if you do switch to PDO `$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', $user, $pwd);` And see RJ's excellent (if graphically naive) tutorial here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php

Comment: If you used prepared statements when both writing and reading, would it help with character encoding issues that this seems to be? It certainly seems to deal with other embedded character issues.

Comment: Never `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` in your code. Enable MySQLi exceptions instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439